# What sudoer spec allows users to mount cifs shares?

Tags: mount, sudo, samba

I'm trying create a line in /etc/sudoers that allows members of group "users" to mount cifs shares anywhere inside their own home directory. In my first attempt I tried:

```
%users ALL=/bin/mount -t cifs /home, /bin/umount /home
```

...which admittedly doesn't restrict them to their own home directory. As a user when I try the command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs ~/mount //hostname/sharename -o username=myuserid,domain=mydomain
```

...I get prompted for the password then receive error:

```
Sorry, user myuserid is not allowed to execute '...command...' as root on servername.
```

Is there any way to coerce sudoers to specify what I want?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do it, less the restriction that you are in your own directory:

```
%users localhost, hostname = NOPASSWD: /bin/mount -t cifs //*/* /home/* -o username=*, /bin/umount /home/*
```

Does anyone have an idea how to restrict a user to hiw own home directory?

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off giving your users the ability to use FUSE filesystems to mount their cifs shares.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that some recent versions of mount.cifs fail unless the mount point is in /etc/fstab, even if they are installed setuid, so I would expect your sudo approach to fail with those versions.

http://fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?p=1329591

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/657900

As an alternative, you might try one of these:

[SMBNetFS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smbnetfs/)

[FuseSMB](http://www.ricardis.tudelft.nl/~vincent/fusesmb/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your requirement must allow users to mount the devices anywhere in their home directory.  Security to keep the device private to them I suppose?

Anyways, if you can handle having public,static mount points you could add entries to /etc/fstab for the cifs shares and add the "users" attribute to let users mount/unmount them.

The line would look something like this:

```
//host/share /mount/point cifs users,rw,username=xxx,password=xxx 0 0
```

See http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html

I realize this doesn't solve the exact issue you presented but maybe it gives you some ideas for a compromise.

Comment: This isn't a very good option for us because we don't know what share they are trying to mound in advance, and because it looks like it requires us to hard-code their AD password into fstab. That's why I'm looking for something more interactive like sudo.

Comment: understandable.  The issue of passwords showing up in /etc/fstab could be avoided with http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/access-windows-shares-from-linux/ but the main problem still exists.

Comment: You don't need to hardcode credentials in `/etc/fstab` if you use option `credentials=` pointing to a file (man mount.cifs). Still it doesn't allow to choose the username, only to protect credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but think of pam_mount solving half of the puzzle already by giving users the ability to mount such networked volumes on start of a session.